# char * as a reference in C

Tags: c

How to pass the param like char * as a reference?

My function uses malloc()

```
void set(char *buf)
{
    buf = malloc(4*sizeof(char));
    buf = "test";
}

char *str;
set(str);
puts(str);
```

Comment: Note for C++ programmers - in C++ you should do this with reference to pointer: `void set(char *& buf){ buf = malloc(5); strcpy(buf, "test"); }` (note there is no `*` at the left of `buf` in func body). This way you can't pass `nullptr` to the function inadvertently.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You pass the address of the pointer:

```
void set(char **buf)
{
    *buf = malloc(5*sizeof(char));
    // 1. don't assign the other string, copy it to the pointer, to avoid memory leaks, using string literal etc.
    // 2. you need to allocate a byte for the null terminator as well
    strcpy(*buf, "test");
}

char *str;
set(&str);
puts(str);
```

Comment: 4 chars is not enough to hold the string, though :) Maybe `sizeof("test")` would be better.

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is `1`, always.

Comment: Why not `malloc(5)` ? it's same as `malloc(5 * sizeof(char))`, because `sizeof(char) = 1` . Unless `sizeof(char)` is mutable and I don't know..

Comment: @NiklasB.: Normally, the people do `strlen("test") + 1` instead of `sizeof("test")` that looks like a good way as well. I will to use it now.

Comment: @Kakashi: `strlen` is calculated at runtime (unless the compiler is clever enough to optimize it)

Comment: @Kakashi KarolyHorvath last comment is very valueable: this will have a big impact on performance. never do something at runtime while you can let the compiler do it for you ;)

Comment: The syntax might not be correct to assign `*buf` the allocation 
use the following LOC if you faced same problem/ 
*buf = static_cast<char *>(malloc(LENGTH)); // Compliant

Answer (score 6):

You have to pass it as a pointer to the pointer:

```
void set(char **buf)
{
    *buf = malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(*buf, "test");
}
```

Call it like this:

```
char *str;
set(&str);
puts(str);
free(str);
```

Note that I have changed the `malloc` call to allocate five characters, that's because you only allocate for the actual characters, but a string also contains a special terminator character and you need space for that as well.

I also use `strcpy` to copy the string to the allocated memory. That is because you are overwriting the pointer otherwise, meaning you loose the pointer you allocate and will have a memory leak.

You should also remember to `free` the pointer when you are done with it, or the memory will stay allocated until the program ends.

Comment: Please mention why you have a "5" instead of a "4".  I cringed when I saw the OP.

Answer (score 4):

C does not support pass by reference. But you can pass a pointer to your pointer, and set that:

```
void set(char **buf)
{
    *buf = malloc(5*sizeof(char)); //5, to make room for the 0 terminator
    strcpy(*buf,"test"); //copy the string into the allocated buffer.
}

char *str;
set(&str);
puts(str);
```

Comment: In computer science, pass by reference means pass an address to a variable. C++ has created a definition that is different from the norm in computer science. That doesn't make the C++ definition the norm, and the question is about C anyhow. Passing by reference in C means passing by pointer. C11 6.2.5 `A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called "pointer to T".`

Comment: One usually distinguishes between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference, in which the reference is passed implicitly. Many languages, like C, is said to only support pass-by-value, though you can emulates pass-by-reference by explicitly passing a pointer to whatever you need a reference to.(that pointer is passed by value though) - so I disagree with your definition.

Comment: Disagree as much as you like, it isn't my definition, it is the C standard's definition of what a reference is in the C language. In the OP's example, buf is a reference to char type. The fact that the reference in itself is passed by value, is another matter.

Answer (score 3):

You to pass a pointer to a pointer, `char**`: there are no references in C.

```
void set(char** buf)
{
    *buf = malloc(5); /* 5, not 4: one for null terminator. */
    strcpy(buf, "test");
}
```

Note that:

```
buf = "test";
```

does not copy `"test"` into `buf`, but points `buf` to the address of the string literal `"test"`. To copy use `strcpy()`.

Remember to `free()` returned buffer when no longer required:

```
char* str;
set(&str);
puts(str);
free(str);
```

Comment: In computer science, pass by reference means pass an address to a variable. C++ has created a definition that is different from the norm in computer science. That doesn't make the C++ definition the norm, and the question is about C anyhow. Passing by reference in C means passing by pointer. C11 6.2.5 `A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called "pointer to T".`

Answer (score 1):

C is pass-by-value. There is no pass-by-reference.

Comment: In computer science, pass by reference means pass an address to a variable. C++ has created a definition that is different from the norm in computer science. That doesn't make the C++ definition the norm, and the question is about C anyhow. Passing by reference in C means passing by pointer. C11 6.2.5 `A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called "pointer to T".`

Comment: @Lundin Do you have a reference for "In computer science, pass by reference means pass an address to a variable"? AFAIK the term pass by reference and its synonyms has been used in their current meaning since Fortran and Pascal, a long time before C++.

Comment: I think we can agree that in general computer science, there is only pass-by-value or pass-by-reference. C and C++ supports a raw version of pass-by-reference called pointers, that allows you modify the actual, reference address if you would like. This feature doesn't stop pointer parameters from being pass-by-reference. In C++ they decided to create an alternative syntax for pass-by-reference, with the C++ reference type. After this, C++ programmers started to believe that the pointer syntax wasn't pass-by-reference any longer. Don't ask me why. ->

Comment: Yes indeed, the pointer in itself is passed by value, it is allocated on the stack/in a register. So what, this is also true for a C++ reference! The resulting machine code is identical.

Comment: @Lundin Re: "I think we can agree that in general computer science, there is only pass-by-value or pass-by-reference." I don't agree; many other (though less common) strategies to pass parameters exist. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy

Answer (score 1):

In the example given above by *hmjd*, it should be:

```
strcpy(*buf, "test");
```

Answer (score 0):

C cannot not pass function arguments by reference, C always passes them by value.

From Kernighan & Ritchie:

> (K&R 2nd, 1.8 Call by value) "In C all function arguments are passed by "value""

To modify a pointer to `T`, you can have a pointer to pointer to `T` as the function argument type.

Comment: In computer science, pass by reference means pass an address to a variable. C++ has created a definition that is different from the norm in computer science. That doesn't make the C++ definition the norm, and the question is about C anyhow. Passing by reference in C means passing by pointer. C11 6.2.5 `A pointer type may be derived from a function type or an object type, called the referenced type. A pointer type describes an object whose value provides a reference to an entity of the referenced type. A pointer type derived from the referenced type T is sometimes called "pointer to T".`

Comment: I don't agree. Using the wording *pass-by-reference* in C can only confuse a little more the beginners: there is no reference in C as there is in C++. Contrary to other languages there aren't two (or more) different ways to pass function arguments in C, you can just pass by value; and pointers arguments are passed the same way as any other argument. And I think the C quote in §6.2.5 has nothing to do with pass-by-reference.

Comment: by the way for the downvoter, I won't delete this answer as I don't think it deserves a `-1` :)

Comment: As you can see for yourself in the above normative text cited from the standard, there is indeed something called reference in C. The definition just isn't what you thought it would be and indeed it is confusing, but it is still there. I didn't downvote you, but I don't believe the whole reference debate is doing the OP any good.